# Adding Logo or Watermark on Save

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, asp.net-mvc

Watermarks or implemented logos annoying when you are presenting a picture on website but i have also concerns about using images without permisson.

Many of you probably know that 9gag was using this till 2016, when you save a picture from website it was adding a 9gag logo to the saved picture.

Honestly, i can't think any way to achive it.

I am using my custom ASP.Net MVC 5 CMS but any front-end solutions will be highly appreciated.

**EDIT**

According to W3 we can recreate images in canvas via JavaScript:

```
window.onload = function() {
    var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
    var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
    var img=document.getElementById("scream");
    ctx.drawImage(img,10,10);
};
```

Since i am redrawing the image, i tink in theory there should be a way to merge two images. Is there anyway to intercept the process and add a logo or watermark?

Comment: Are you saying you want to display images within your page *without* watermarks, but somehow add a watermark if the user tries to save the image? I don't think that is possible.

Comment: front-end solutions would involve `canvas` - what you are describing does sound possible, but very easily circumvented, which is probably why,as you say, 9gag **was** doing that

Comment: If you are trying to add a watermark with a canvas element that means you'd still have to download the original image to the browser, which means the user could figure out the URL and download it directly. Or copy it out of the browser cache. Or disable your JS. Etc.

Comment: @nnnnnn yes, i know that it is impossible unless image file itself physically watermarked (thats why stock photo websites do it) but we are talking about everyday John Doe, probably has no idea about DOM, console etc. also merging two images with javascript can be usefull for other applications.

Answer (score 1):

Short version: don't think it's possible without a hack. If you want a watermark in the lower righthand corner, copy the bottom few pixels for each image, put the watermark on the full image, and hover the original corner over it.

Long version:
You can't intercept the "right click->Save Image As" functionality of the browser. What you can do is a kind of hack where the underlying image has the watermark, but you cover the watermark with the old copy of the image. If you want to put your website's name in the lower righthand corner of your images, then copy that small sliver of the image, then put the watermark there. Now in your app put two images wrapped in a div with relative positioning. Make the div the size of the original image, with absolute positioning and top/left: 0px, then put the corner on top and do bottom/right: 0px. Then if they right click anywhere but the bottom righthand corner and save, they'll get the image underneath, which has the watermark.

Comment: Clever, but a simple screenshot would work around this, no?

Comment: @nnnnnn screenshot is always a solution but resolution will be bad so...

Comment: @Dustin Kane actually i tought about that too but that means that serving the same photo (not same but, different) twice and i don't think that is a good idea. but thanks anyways.

Comment: Not actually the WHOLE image twice, since you only need to serve the bottom corner of the image (which will only be a few pixels and, thus, very small)